# Android - WebView not saving input forms

Tags: android, android-studio, web-applications, webview

I'm using a simple webView client in my android application, but, when the user log in, close the app and open app again the input forms not save the user information like webbrowser.
How i solve it?
I need when the user enter the 'username' the app save this like a webbrowser, if possible save the password too :)

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the tutorial on the Android Developer site from Google?. I think that this is what you are looking forward to achieve....

**"" Building Apps with Contacts & Sign-In ""**

https://developer.android.com/training/building-userinfo.html